# Button inside asp:Panel causes exception in IE10 only

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a `LinkButton` within an `asp:Panel`. When I click the confirmation button, I see the following in the IE10 console:

`SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, Could not complete the operation due to error 80700013.`

and

`SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0`

When I look in the event viewer I see this:

```
    Exception information: 
    Exception type: ArgumentNullException 
    Exception message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: exception
   at System.Web.UI.AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs..ctor(Exception exception)
   at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.OnPageError(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.general_resetpassword_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

This happens **only** in IE10. In IE9, IE8, Chrome and Firefox this works and I am redirected to continue the flow of the application.
I am on asp.net 4.0, IIS7.5 and Windows server 2008 r2.

I have already installed `KB2600088`, so this is not the issue. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Checked [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) ?

Comment: @HarshBaid: As I said, we already installed the update `KB2600088`.

Comment: As the exception is in the constructor of `AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs` and the missing parameter is `exception`, I believe the exception is a general issue with the framework.

Comment: Check and verify that you don't have two `form` tags from the page source view..

Comment: @HarshBaid I checked. Just one, but if I had more than one, wouldn`t it cause an issue in all browsers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I got tired of messing around with this I just removed the 'Panel' and everything works as it should. I also opened a case with Microsoft MSDN support, just for laughs.